# How to trigger Masonry when a category gets clicked on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I am using the wonderful [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com) cascading grid layout library to display a number of `projects` on my website.

This is my javascript:

```
var container = document.querySelector('#projects');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  columnWidth: 280,
  itemSelector: '.project'
});
```

Now, in the sidebar of my website I am also listing the various `categories` that my `projects` belong to, so a user can filter them.

It would be nice if a click on a category would also trigger the masonry effect, a bit like in [this example](http://demo.templaza.com/joomla-template/2012/world-travel-ii).

How can this be achieved?

I am fairly new to Javascript and jQuery, so the solution is probably a simple one.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by appending new bricks to the container and run it with masonry.reload() with option animate enable. Instead to use append you can also use prepend. You can also check this site http://www.maxmedia.com.

Comment: Thanks. I studied your code but it's too advanced for a javascript n00b like me. Would you care to provide a code snippet?

Comment: I tried to email you through your website but: `Delivery Status Notification (Failure)`

Comment: I just did. Hope you received it.

Answer (score -2):

Take a peek at the JQuery Isotope plugin: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

It can do sorting and filtering in the Masonry style.